# 3D Mapped Graph with Gnuplot Not accurate

Tags: graph, 3d, gnuplot

I am encountering problems while trying to create a 3D (2D mapped) graph.

The data I am generating should create a 3 dimensional normal distribution bump, or, when "mapped", it should look like a flattened 3D graph, with color used as the third dimension

The script I am using to generate the mapped graph is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

reset

#set terminal png
set term postscript eps enhanced

set size square
set xlabel "X position"
set ylabel "Y position"
#set zlabel "Synaptic Strength"

#Have a gradient of colors from blue (low) to red (high)
set pm3d map
set palette rgbformulae 22,13,-31

#set xrange [0:110]
#set yrange [0:80]
#set zrange [0:1]

set style line 1 lw 1

#set title "Title"

#Don't want a key
unset key

#set the number of samples
set dgrid3d 51,51

set hidden3d

splot DataFile u 1:2:3
```

when I run it on the following DataFile (http://www.sendspace.com/file/ppibyw)

I get the following output
[image]

The legend indicates a z-range of 0-0.03, however, the datafile has far larger z-values, such as 0.1. Obviously I can't publish a graph that is so inaccurate. Furthermore, I need a better graph in order to gain a better insight as to what is wrong with my simulation.

Does anyone know why gnuplot handles 3d mapped graphs like this? I suspect it has to do with the number, and nature, of the samples.

Comment: Hi puk,
I gave your script a try and can reproduce the obvious error (version 4.4). I would try two things: 1: As you suggested, reduce the number of points and see what happens. 2: Reduce the number of digits of each number.
As a last resort you could ticket your findings [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=2055&atid=102055).

Comment: @Woltan I looked around and I narrowed down the problem to averaging of edges. So if you have a 3x3 array of [0,0,0, 0,100,0,  0,0,0] the value of 100 will be averaged based on all surrounding zeros. I found a solution to this which draws a series of small boxes per matrix value, but it crashes b/c I had way too many values, at which point I gave up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You problem is in the `set dgrid3d 51,51`

Have a look at what happens if you write `set dgrid3d 51,102` (much better) or set `dgrid3d 51,500` (much worse)

The point is that (from the help)

> The grid  is equally spaced in x
>   (rows) and in y (columns); the z
>   values are computed  as weighted
>   averages or spline interpolations of
>   the scattered points' z   values. In
>   other words, a regularly spaced grid
>   is created and the a smooth 
>   approximation to the raw data is
>   evaluated for all grid points. **Only
>   this  approximation is plotted, but
>   not the raw data.**

You could try and improve the approximation if you want see the help (?dgrid3d), but I would rather just plot the data straight.  You can do this by ditching the dgrid3d command altogether.  You will have to modify your data file so that there is a blank line when the x coordinate changes.  For example

```
3.10000000000000142109 4.15692193816530508599 0.00004084299890679580
3.10000000000000142109 4.33012701892219364908 0.00001123746243460237

3.15000000000000124345 0.08660254037844386521 0.00000816290100763514
3.15000000000000124345 0.25980762113533162339 0.00001935936190868058
```

Then with this simplified script

```
set terminal png![enter image description here][1]

#set size square
set xlabel "X position"
set ylabel "Y position"

#uncomment the next command to eliminate the mysterious glitch around x=3.4
set yrange [0.1:4.5]
set pm3d map

set output "grid_merged.png"
splot "grid_merged2.dat" u 1:2:3 
set output
set term pop
```

I get [image: plotting the actual data rather than interpolated data]

which is better than you get with the interpolated plot.  I'm not sure what causes the glitch aroung 3.4, its not there on other (non-mapped) views - altering the yrange eliminates it - although I'm not sure it changing the y-range is cheating in terms of your simulation results....